# Spring problem to load stored procedure to H2 database

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, h2

I try create stored procedur in H2 in Spring in several ways:

1)

```
CREATE ALIAS get_some AS $$ String getSome(String value){return "{\"name\": \"Jan\"}";} $$;
```

Error:

```
1086 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [data.sql]: CREATE ALIAS get_some AS $$ String getSome(String val
ue){return "{\"name\": \"Jan\"}"
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE ALIAS get_some AS [*]$$ String getSome(String value){return ""{\""name\"": \""Jan\""}""" [42000-200]

1086 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of class path resource [data.sql]: } $$
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "} [*]$$"; SQL statement:
} $$ [42000-200]
```

2. CREATE ALIAS get_some AS $$ String getSome(String value){return '{"name": "Jan"}';} $$;

Error:

```
1124 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [data.sql]: CREATE ALIAS get_some AS $$ String getSome(String val
ue){return '{"name": "Jan"}'
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE ALIAS get_some AS [*]$$ String getSome(String value){return '{""name"": ""Jan""}'" [42000-200]

1124 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of class path resource [data.sql]: } $$
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "} [*]$$"; SQL statement:
} $$ [42000-200]
```

3. CREATE ALIAS get_some AS $$ String getSome(String value){return "Hello world";} $$;

Error:

```
1103 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [data.sql]: CREATE ALIAS get_some AS $$ String getSome(String val
ue){return "Hello world"
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE ALIAS get_some AS [*]$$ String getSome(String value){return ""Hello world""" [42000-200]

1103 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of class path resource [data.sql]: } $$
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "} [*]$$"; SQL statement:
} $$ [42000-200]
```

4. CREATE ALIAS get_some FOR "H2StoredProcedure.getSome";

Class:

```
package pl.some.procedure;
public class H2StoredProcedure {
    public static String getSome(final String inValue) {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

Error:

```
1156 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [data.sql]: CREATE ALIAS get_some FOR "H2StoredProcedure.getSome"

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Class "H2StoredProcedure" not found; SQL statement:
CREATE ALIAS get_some FOR "H2StoredProcedure.getSome" [90086-200]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: H2StoredProcedure
```

5. CREATE ALIAS get_some FOR "pl.some.procedure.H2StoredProcedure.getSome";

No error:

```
1124 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - 0 returned as update count for SQL: CREATE ALIAS get_some FOR "pl.opl.procedure.H2StoredProcedure.getSome"
1124 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - Executed SQL script from class path resource [data.sql] in 0 ms.
```

but other application when try call get_some have an error:

```
2020-07-31 15:08:06,037 [[eee].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.06] D-CCC INFO  pl.other.esb.controller.MyController - Class "pl.some.procedure.H2StoredProcedure" not found; SQL statement:
 call wow.get_some(?)  [90086-200]
```

How can I write correct procedure to load in Spring ?

Comment: Just use standard string literals (`"Java code"`) instead of `$$` literals, and don't forget to repeat each double quote twice in that literal. Spring doesn't support `$$` literals.

Comment: I don't know how ... please write some example .. thanks

Comment: I tried CREATE ALIAS get_some AS "String getSome(String value){return ""Hello world"";}";   but still wrong : Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [data.sql]: CREATE ALIAS get_some AS "String getSome(String value
){return ""Hello world"";}"
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "String getSome(String value){return ""Hello world"";}" not found; SQL statement:
CREATE ALIAS get_some AS "String getSome(String value){return ""Hello world"";}" [42122-200]

Comment: Sorry, I meant `'Java code'` in single quotes (and single quotes need to be repeated, but you don't have them).

Comment: not work :( I tried this: CREATE ALIAS get_some AS 'String getSome(String value){return ''Hello world'';}';   but I gave error:    org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "/org/h2/dynamic/GET_SOME.java:6: error: unclosed character literal
    public static String getSome(String value){return 'Hello world';}
                                                      ^
/org/h2/dynamic/GET_SOME.java:6: error: unclosed character literal
    public static String getSome(String value){return 'Hello world';}

Comment: ok I have a solution! 
Not this: CREATE ALIAS get_some AS 'String getSome(String value){return ''Hello world'';}';
but this is correct: CREATE ALIAS get_some AS 'String getSome(String value){return "Hello world";}';